# xp_xmdshell azure data factory

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am wondering if I use SQL Server stored procedure inside "Execute SQL Task" in SSIS and this stored procedure uses `xp_cmdshell`. Now if I want to create Azure Data Factory pipeline for the same task, how do I achieve that?

Also I have some C# readonly and readwrite variables inside my SSIS, How do I convert them in ADF?

Comment: Hi,your question is off-topic here.Please provide your configuration info or any error details.What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks Jay but ADF is pretty new technology and all the demos\tutorials talks about  copy data from source to destination. I have SPs inside SSIS that uses xp_cmdshell. Microsoft says you can use Custom tasks and achieve anything but how?? Its nowhere out there. thats why I asking experts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft says you can use Custom tasks and achieve anything but how??

For you situation,maybe you could use [Stored Procedure Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) to run your SSIS package.Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-stored-procedure-activity

For that,you need to configure [Azure-SSIS integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-invoke-ssis-package-stored-procedure-activity#create-an-azure-ssis-integration-runtime),not default Azure IR.